# Magento - CDN and base url conflict

Tags: magento, cdn

I am trying to set up another domain to serve static content.I have found good articles (http://www.riyaz.net/blogging/setup-own-cdn/890/) explaining how to do that.

I created a CNAME record(js.domain.com) pointing to main domain. Also created a subdomain js.domain.com  with document root same as domain.com
But now when I visit js.domain.com it keeps redirecting to domain.com because of magento base url. 
How this can be avoided or I am doing any thing wrong in setting UP my CDN for static content. In the end I dont want to maintain two separate document roots for my CDN and main domain.

Comment: How did you do the above exactly? (esp document root)

Answer (score 0):

Your base_url needs to be www.domain.com

Change only the url for media, skin etc to js.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you misconfigured your vhost config, if it is accessed on js.domain.com you shouldn't load Magento itself. You can accomplish this by creating a custom htaccess (in vhost config) for it